# Proteção de dados sensíveis em seu banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, segurança, criptografia

Qual a maneira mais adequada para proteger dados sensíveis, como: CPF, número do cartão de crédito, cvv, data de expiração, etc.?

Nunca precisei guardar esse tipo de dados em minhas aplicações, pois utilizo API que fazem o tratamento deles e retornam o que eu quero.

Porém agora houve a necessidade de guardá-los em meu DB. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Depende, você vai precisar ler os dados de volta? Por exemplo, com senhas o indicado é guardar um hash, que não é reversível, pois isso basta para implementar um processo de login. Caso precise dos dados de volta, vai precisar usar algo como criptografia assimétrica. Tudo depende do uso. CPF nem sei se valeria a pena criptografar...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A única forma que deve fazer isto é usando a criptografia original do banco de dados. Mesmo assim espera-se que toda a infra esteja bem protegida porque se acontecer uma invasão em camadas mais baixas vai abrindo portas para a segurança ser burlada até nesta condição. Se isto já é difícil ser feito direito imagina tentar alguma coisa manual por conta própria, nem tente.

Se o banco de dados não suportar nada pronto e que seja conhecido como algo bom então terá que achar uma solução própria de acordo com o banco em questão e assumirá o risco. Obviamente isto envolve criptografia também.

Mas entenda que boa parte das tentativas de roubar esses dados nem serão no banco de dados mas no momento que você descriptografa essa informação para usá-la, é muito mais fácil e é onde as pessoas cometem mais erros.

Ou seja, se não tiver especialistas em segurança é melhor não fazer isto, é muito arriscado.

Eu tentaria não guardar dados realmente sensíveis e principalmente sem a pessoa dona dos dados saber que isto está ocorrendo. Consulte um advogado especializado para ver o que ele acha de você guardar o dado de alguém que pode ser usado para criar fraudes ou mesmo violar a privacidade.

Uma coisa é guardar dados que na verdade são públicos (CPF) ou dados que você tem controle, como senhas, outra é guardar dados completos do cartão de crédito.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Realmente isso que eu pensei. Não preciso de todos os dados do cartão, apenas os que são pedidos pelo antifraude que estamos utilizando. O que vou ter que fazer é passar esses dados na requisição direto para o antifraude evitando ter que guarda-los no meu db

Comment: Ou guardar nada.

Comment: Boa pergunta ! Podem existir n camadas de proteção e um funcionário vazar os dados, CPFs podem ser comprados, aqui no Rio , na porta de um centro comercial. Não sei se vale a pena guardar "tudo" criptografado. Já existe norma da ABNT sobre isto ?

Comment: Não sei dizer..